# Topology of point wise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I encountered this topology in the exercise below. I was wondering if there is any connection to algebraic geometry? This looks like algebraic geometry but instead of points we are dealing with functions. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this has nothing to do with Algebraic Geometry. It is a way of defining a topology in the space of all functions from a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ such that a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of functions from $X$ into $Y$ converges to a function $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ if and only if$$(\forall x\in X):\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x).$$

Comment: Jose do you happen to have some way I can contact you? I would like to discuss this further with you.

Comment: Why not in here?

Comment: The way I visualize this statement that $f \in V_1^{(x_1)} \cap \ldots \cap V_n^{(x_n)}$ is it some hyperplane of functions determined by the solutions to $x_i$. Do you agree somewhat to this statement?

Comment: No, not at all. Even if $X=Y=\mathbb R^n$, those sets would never be hyperplanes.

Comment: I mean hyperplanes of functions not points.

Comment: I understood that. And they are *not* hyperplanes. Besides, if $X$ and $Y$ have no algeraic structure, it is meaningless to assert that those sets are (or aren't) hyperplanes.

Comment: Yeah I see. Is it possible after adding some extra structure on X and Y to get hyperplanes with respect to the settings above ? I mean what I have in mind can we do algebraic geometry with functions instead of points ?

Comment: No. Those sets will never be hyperplanes.

Comment: Thanks for all your input.